# Why do I see a 20 Volts peak-to-peak sinudoidal signal @ 50 Hz on my ESD mat cover?

Tags: ground, grounding, esd

I accidentally touched the ESD mat cover on the my table with oscilloscope probe[voltage probe, 700MHz]. It is shown a pure sinusoidal signal with an amplitude of near 20Volt peak-to-peak @50Hz on the oscilloscope screen. I have checked my ESD mat ground connection, and ground connection looked proper. Why do I see this signal on the my grounded ESD mat? Is it possible that Grounding is not enough ?

Regards,

Comment: You might see it even in the air as long as the probe is not grounded...

Comment: Because you don't live in a country with 60hz power. But seriously it's capacitive coupling, 50Hz is all around you. It's really just an artifact of the scope and your grounding scheme though and has high impedance.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I knew the mat is already ground itself.  So, where should I take a 'ground'?

Comment: The mat is not a ground as explained by the answer, but a huge resistor connected to the ground.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure. From where the mat receive 50Hz sinusoidal? Because it is seen that the mat is only connected to the ground.

Comment: @doner_t: From all around.  Imagine a capacitor, your mat is one plate, the air is the dielectric, and the plate being driven is all the things carrying mains current around you.

Comment: There are electric fields all around you from mains power. Sometimes the probe will pick up a voltage from the electric field, but if the probe is connected properly to the circuit you are measuring, you will not see the 50 Hz (60 Hz in North America). So whenever you see a big 50 Hz signal that you are not expecting, check the probe connection to the circuit, including the GND of the probe.

Comment: If you touch probe ground to probe tip, that will neutralize the 50 Hz also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the mat as one plate of a parallel-plate capacitor, and the wiring (those round wires in the walls, or your scope power cord, etc) as the other flat plate of the capacitor. Yes, the wires are not flat, but we'll assume they are, so the formula becomes so simple you will remember and will use the formula in the future.

C (parallel plates) = Eo * Er * Area/Distance.

C = 8.9e-12 farad/meter * Er=1 for air * 1 square meter Area / 1meter distance.

C = 8.91e-12 farad/meter * 1 meter = 8.9pF ~~ 10pf (accurate enough).

What is the current induced in the "plate"?

I = C * dV/dT

I = 10pF * [ 220vac * 1.414 * radian frequency ]

I = 10pF * [300volts_peak * (6.28 * 50)] =  10pF * 300 * ~300

I = 10pF * 90,000 = 1e-11 * 9e+4 = 9e-7 or ~~~ 1uA

The impedance of your probe is 10Mohms.

10MegOhms * 1uA == 10 volts peak, and you measured 20 volts PP.

Sorry for this being so accurate a SWAG

Answer (score 3):

Static Dissipating mats are rated in units of GigaOhms per square and not 1M Ohm like wrist straps.

So you would get likely more voltage on your 10:1 probe by touching the tip with your 50~100pF finger tip using your body as an E field collector.  The impedance of such mats is not a simple ground but a static dissipating insulator.

If you doubt the suitability of your mat, do some surge current test with a 50 ohm measurement method to measure xx uV current rise time and amplitude across an interface 50Ohm shunt to coax to DSO.

I can dig up test methods, but the concept of protect is a matter of voltage and Z(f) impedance.  I can [dig](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7Vl8PEOwb8YJ:https://www.elimstat.com/2017/05/26/how-to-use-esd-meter-to-test-mats/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=firefox-b-ab) up test methods if concerned. ANSI/ESD S4.1 "Worksurfaces - Resistance Measurements".

Comment: "Resistance per square" is an interesting phenomenon for those of us afflicted with an inquiring mind.  EEVBlog has some excellent coverage on this specific topic... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME4Xe53TMxI

Comment: @Tony Stewart.EE since'75. Thank you for reply. So, could we say that ESD mat is not a pure ground? But, I still could not get it from where my ESD mat receive city electricity.

Comment: It is a leaky insulator connected to a ground so discharge is limited to uA and stretched over a long time duration >> microsecond  Being high impedance, it can pickup induced stray line voltages from your power cables or even from you acting as a conduit.  Perhaps if a ground plane was installed underneath, you would not see this but generally ESD is a breakdown of voltage and damaged by current, so this limits the current

Comment: "But, I still could not get it from where my ESD mat receive city electricity." Its coming from the oscilloscope itself. With many megohms of resistance on the mat, it only takes a tiny bit of stray current to induce the voltage you are seeing. That stray current is coming from your oscilloscope.